# Errors installing mysqlclient on Max OSX

Tags: mysql, python-3.6

I am trying to install mysqlclient on Mac OSX, as required by Django to use MySql rather than sqlite DB.

I originally tried `pip3 install mysqlclient` but I was getting an error like this:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3f/1z_bg4h52lz8n0_gc1mp7gwh0000gn/T/pip-install-em4vq6dr/mysqlclient/
```

I have done a lot of Googling and tried so many suggestions (this appears a common issue), and I've ended up with even more of a mess of an error message now:

```
Collecting mysqlclient==1.3.1
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6b/ba/4729d99e85a0a35bb46d55500570de05b4af10431cef174b6da9f58a0e50/mysqlclient-1.3.1.tar.gz (76kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 2.0MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/z_/k_j3hrx10gn5w244fpvzw01r0000gn/T/pip-install-4nhdinpy/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /private/var/folders/z_/k_j3hrx10gn5w244fpvzw01r0000gn/T/pip-wheel-41536ku7 --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
  copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
  creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
  running build_ext
  building '_mysql' extension
  creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
  gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,3,1,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.15/include/mysql -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.o
  _mysql.c:40:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found
  #include "my_config.h"
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
  Running setup.py install for mysqlclient ... error
    Complete output from command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/z_/k_j3hrx10gn5w244fpvzw01r0000gn/T/pip-install-4nhdinpy/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/z_/k_j3hrx10gn5w244fpvzw01r0000gn/T/pip-record-o9decnbp/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    copying _mysql_exceptions.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/compat.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/converters.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/connections.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/cursors.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    copying MySQLdb/times.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb
    creating build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CR.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/ER.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/FLAG.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/REFRESH.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    copying MySQLdb/constants/CLIENT.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/MySQLdb/constants
    running build_ext
    building '_mysql' extension
    creating build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6
    gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -arch x86_64 -g -Dversion_info=(1,3,1,'final',1) -D__version__=1.3.1 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.15/include/mysql -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-3.6/_mysql.o
    _mysql.c:40:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found
    #include "my_config.h"
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3.6 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/z_/k_j3hrx10gn5w244fpvzw01r0000gn/T/pip-install-4nhdinpy/mysqlclient/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/z_/k_j3hrx10gn5w244fpvzw01r0000gn/T/pip-record-o9decnbp/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/z_/k_j3hrx10gn5w244fpvzw01r0000gn/T/pip-install-4nhdinpy/mysqlclient/
```

Anybody have any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong?

Using Python 3.6

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 8):

Have fixed it based on this post - https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/issues/169#issuecomment-306821834 - but I only did this bit:

ran `brew info openssl`

than entered the following as two separate commands

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include"
```

Then:

```
pip3 install mysqlclient

Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f4/f1/3bb6f64ca7a429729413e6556b7ba5976df06019a5245a43d36032f1061e/mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
  Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/chris/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/30/91/e0/2ee952bce05b1247807405c6710c6130e49468a5240ae27134
Successfully built mysqlclient
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.4.2.post1
```